# Trying to create a for loop in R

Tags: r

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7vyg.png)

The question is I am trying to establish a for loop with two variable i and j, Variable i contains only 3 different character "BCC" "FCC" and "Other", and j is numerical. As you seem above I trys to have AG_BCC0.2 = AG_BCC0.2 +1 everytime the if statement is statisfy but currently I do not know how to finish this code. The code language is Rstudio

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example on how to ask a question at SO

Comment: please make your question minimal AND reproducible. Refer to the FAQ to see how (or click the link above)